# How to print java System.out.println in jmeter UI Listner response data

Tags: java, jmeter

I just started playing with jmeter, I wrote a small java sampler test, which send request to server and get a UUID in response, I am printing this response as System.out.println in my test

I am running jmeter on windows, so this response get printed on cmd window and not in jmeter UI Listener, which is right ( since cmd is console out )

I wanted to find out, if there is any way to setup logger ? 
what are standard practices to handle these situation in jmeter ?

I will appreciate if someone can explain with a small example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the the command-line option `-j jmeterlogfile`

Comment: Is there any option in UI ? is this the only way ?

Comment: Options > Log Viewer displays the log file in a bottom pane on main JMeter window.

Comment: If it helped you, then accept the answer by clicking checked marked on the left side and vote the answer up :-) thank you

Comment: I am a newbie here, cant vote up even if i want ( i dont have 15 rep ) sorry !!