# How to redirect jmeter stdout to a file

Tags: java, jmeter

I am running behind this from last few hours, earlier asked similar question but this is more specific for my needs, I have a java sampler test with a lot of `System.out.println("")` when i run my jmeter test, all these output go to cmd window

I want to redirect output of these `System.out.println("")` to a desired location, what are my options ?
I am using jmeter on windows

My last question : [How to print java System.out.println in jmeter UI Listner response data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28818445/4556894)

Comment: Why doesn't your previous question solve this for you?

Comment: Answer mentioned in previous, is printing jmeter internal thread logs ( if i understand correctly ) I dont see any of stdout being printed there.

Comment: what happens when you use `-l logFile` command-line option?

Comment: @Mazaneciha : I am trying everything on UI and I believe you are talking about -J logfile, this option can be set in UI also from options > Log Viewer 
so I think it wont make any difference if i run on command line but i will try and come up with my findings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Findings, Hope this will help someone

- If you are running jmeter in UI mode, you can get jmeter internal test logs my enabling log viewer  `Options > Log Viewer`
- If you want these logs into a file, uncomment this property   `#log_file=jmeter.log` in `$JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter.properties`
- If you wan to find all stdout ( like System.out.println in my case), look for this file `$JMETER_HOME/bin/root.log`

Finally If you want samilar logs as mentioned in point 1, on command line, use `-l {log_file_name}` option

Comment: There is no $JMETER_HOME/bin/root.log - at least not anymore.
(tested with JMeter 3.2)
Nor a log_file entry in jmeter.properties file.
> a.txt 2>&1 could be a good choice.